# Program to print Star(*) triangle on Right Side(Opposite Side) in C++ using For Loop or If Statement

Tags: c++

I have a task to complete the task is to print Star(*)Triangle on right side in C++ using For Loop/if statement i write program but it give output like this.

[image]

But i want to output like this.

```
**********
 *********
  ********
   *******
    ******
     *****
      ****
       ***
        **
         *
```

So, please help or tell me by making what changes in my code i can print triangle like this.

//Program to print triangle on Right Side.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{int number, i,j;
 cout << "Enter the Number :";
 cin >> number;

 for (i=number; i>=1; i--)
 {
 for (j=1; j<=i; j++)
 {
     if (j==1 || j==i || i==number)
     {
        cout << "*";
     }
     else
     {
         cout << " ";
     }
 }
    cout << endl;
 }
 getch();
 return 0;
 }
```

I think that may be some changing in if statement can generate triangle that i want but i am unable to do give me some advice so i can solve this.

Comment: Odd that I can't see that program outputting what you say it does. Looks to me like the triangle should be hollow.

Comment: Suggestion: Don't think about the code for a while. Figure out an algorithm. Start by drawing the image you want by hand and take really good notes of what you did. These notes will directly translate into the operations you must perform and the order you must perform it in. That's the start of the algorithm. If you just try to write code without planning, you will fail so often that the time wasted will prevent you from effectively learning. Cutting and pasting solutions from the Internet, especially the wrong solution, is a similar waste of your time.

Comment: Hint: You need another for loop somewhere that adds spaces before the (*) symbols

Comment: You are Right @user4581301 & start by drawing is a good idea. i will surely try this.
Thanks

Comment: @AlexanderFreyr thanks & your hint is very useful for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i, j, k,number;
    cin>>number;
    for(i=number;i>=1;i--)
    {
        for(j=number;j>i;j--)
        {
            cout << " ";
        }
        for(k=1;k<=i;k++)
        {
            cout << "*";            
        }
        cout <<endl;        
    }
    return 0;
}
```